# Volume of Cylinder and Ellipsoid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification, volume

[image]

In $\mathbb{R}^3$ I have to find the volume of the domain which lies inside both the cylinder of equation $x^2+y^2=1$ and the ellipsoid with equation $4x^2+4x^2+z^2=64$, where $(x,y,z)$ are Cartesian Coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The cylinder and the ellipsoid are shown at the graph. The domain in question is a tube domain with the side surface being the surface of the cylinder, and the top and the bottom parts of its boundary being parts of the surface of the ellipsoid.

**Approach:**
First, I substitute with cylindrical coordinates as follows:
$r^2=x^2+y^2, \tan(θ)=y/x$ and $z=z$
From the equation of the cylinder I get that $r^2=1$ and from the equation of the ellipsoid that $z^2=64-4r^2 \Rightarrow z=\pm \sqrt{64-4r^2}$. Replacing with $r^2=1$ in the equation of the ellipsoid i get the solutions $z=\pm 2\sqrt{15}$.

**Question:**

In order to find the volume in question I am considering the triple integral(s) for $-1\leq r \leq 1$, $0 \leq θ \leq 2π$ and for $-2\sqrt{15} \leq z \leq 2\sqrt{15}$.
Are these boundaries correct?

Since $z=\pm \sqrt{64-4r^2}$, it is broken into two functions, namely $z= \sqrt{64-4r^2}$ for which the boundaries of $r$ and $θ$ will remain the same but the boundaries of $z$ would be $ 0 \leq z \leq 2\sqrt{15}$ and $z= -\sqrt{64-4r^2}$ for which the boundaries of $r$ and $θ$ will remain the same but the boundaries of $z$ would be $ -2\sqrt{15}\leq z \leq 0$. And thus I will calculate the triple integrals. Is this approach correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: $r$ must not be negative. It represents the radial distance from the $z$-axis to the walls of the cylinder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral you're looking for is

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_{-\sqrt{64-4r^2}}^{\sqrt{64-4r^2}} r \, dz \, dr \, d\theta$$

For any point $(x,y,z)$ in the region of interest, the $z$-coordinate is bounded above and below by the halves of an ellipsoid, $z=\pm\sqrt{64-4r^2}$. The bounds of $z$ cannot be constant, since the $z$-coordinate depends on both $x$ and $y$.